# How to Pick from an union Type like an Interface

Tags: typescript

In Typescript you can pick a set of properties from an Interface like:

```js
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

type TodoPreview = Pick<Todo, "title" | "completed">;
```

but is there a way to do something with an union Type like:

```js
type CarModel = 'mercedes' | 'audi' | 'fiat'
type MyCarModel = Pick<CarModel, 'mercedes' | 'fiat'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type MyCarModel = Extract<CarModel, 'mercedes' | 'fiat'>;
```

Use [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility type.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Utility types to be of help:

```
type CarModel = 'mercedes' | 'audi' | 'fiat'
type MyCarModel = Extract<CarModel, 'mercedes' | 'fiat'>
type MyCarModel2 = Exclude<CarModel, 'audi'>
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJwLIHsAmEA2UC8UDkAthAgMYQYDO%20UAPgXAK5oCWN9%20AZi3MPgLAAoUJChIQ8ZOiy4oAUQAewBHFLAAPJNQZMAGgLEyFCNToFuvfAD4hI6OK3TMAJlmLSmZhE2JtWffhMrNZAA)